# Is there an Arctic Circle phenomenon for Amman-Beenker tilings?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, rt.representation-theory

I found some slides on [tilings](http://media.scgp.stonybrook.edu/presentations/20130221_2_-_random_-_tilings_-_christoph_richard.pdf) and one of them pertained to [Amman-Beenker](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3545) tilings.  It looks like there is an Arctic Circle phenomenon similar to that for dominos or lozenges.  Is there any mathematical way of proving it? (Maybe [not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78497/arctic-regions-in-higher-dimensional-zonotopes)?)

[image]